# Query with multiple conditions in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have a question that may be silly. In Yii2, I have this $query (declared by self::find()) with some ground conditions:

```php
        $query->andWhere(['>=', 'mrd.created', $start_date]);
        $query->andWhere(['<=', 'mrd.created', $end_date. ' 23:59:59']);
```

And the result I want to return by this select: the `user_id` that has `created` in time from `$start_date` to `end_date` and `cons_debit` in the same time but not depending on `created`

```php
$result = $query->select(['mrd.user_id', 'SUM(mrd.actual_revenue) AS total_revenue', 
         'cons_debit' => new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(CASE WHEN mrd.fail_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date THEN mrd.cons_debit ELSE 0 END)', [
                ':from_date' => $start_date,
                ':to_date' => $end_date. ' 23:59:59',
            ])])
                ->groupBy(['mrd.user_id'])
                ->offset(max($params['page'] - 1, 0) * $params['limit'])
                ->orderBy(['total_revenue'=>SORT_DESC])
                ->limit($params['limit'])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
```

The problem I encounter is with `cons_debit` select. I only want to retrive SUM(cons_debit) that has `fail_date` between `from_date` and `to_date` (not depending on `mrd.created`).

I can have this result with 2 query, but I want to know if there is any way to achieve this in one query.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer to this, it is kind of simple :v

```php
$result = $query->select(['mrd.user_id', 'SUM(mrd.actual_revenue) AS total_revenue', 
                 '(SELECT SUM(cons_debit) FROM mass_revenue_date WHERE user_id = mrd.user_id AND fail_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date) AS cons_debit',])
                ->groupBy(['mrd.user_id'])
                ->offset(max($params['page'] - 1, 0) * $params['limit'])
                ->orderBy(['total_revenue'=>SORT_DESC])
                ->params([
                    ':from_date' => $start_date,
                    ':to_date' => $end_date,
                ])
                ->limit($params['limit'])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
```